# When fullscreen then inputs are getting covered by keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I searched but found no solution. My problem is when im forcing fullscreen on the app the input is getting covered by the keyboard. If i remove the fullscreen then it is working again. Is it possible to make fullscreen and prevent inputs getting covered by keyboard?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post more details about your issue?

Comment: if possible please attached screenshot of your problem.